# Trying to get all image links of reddit.com using python and re

Tags: python-2.7

I've looked through other posts and have tried to implement what they have said into my code but I'm still missing something.

What I am trying to do is get all the image links off a website, specifically reddit.com
and once I obtain the links to display the images in my browser or download them and display them through Windows Image Viewer.  I am just trying to practice and broaden my python skills.

I am stuck at obtaining the links and choosing how to display the images.
What I have right now is:

```
import urllib2
import re
links=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.reddit.com").read()
found=re.findall("http://imgur.com/+\w+.jpg", links)
print found #Just for testing purposes, to see what links are found
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try employing BeautifulSoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) rather than a regexp? Might make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `imgur.com` links on reddit do *not* have any `.jpg` extensions, so your regular expression won't match anything. You should be looking for the `i.imgur.com` domain instead.

Matching `re.findall("http://i.imgur.com/\w+.jpg", links)` does return results:

```
>>> re.findall("http://i.imgur.com/\w+.jpg", links)
['http://i.imgur.com/PMNZ2.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/akg4l.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/dAHtq.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/dAHtq.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/nT73r.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/nT73r.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/z2wIl.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/z2wIl.jpg']
```

You can expand this to other file extensions:

```
>>> re.findall("http://i.imgur.com/\w+.(?:jpg|gif|png)", links)
['http://i.imgur.com/PMNZ2.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/akg4l.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/dAHtq.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/dAHtq.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/rsIfN.png', 'http://i.imgur.com/rsIfN.png', 'http://i.imgur.com/nT73r.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/nT73r.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/bPs5N.gif', 'http://i.imgur.com/z2wIl.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/z2wIl.jpg']
```

You may want to use a proper HTML parser instead of a regular expression; I can recommend both [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [`lxml`](http://lxml.de). It'll make it much easier to find all `<img />` tags that use `i.imgur.com` links with those tools, including `.gif` and `.png` files, if any.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly.  I didn't understand how to use the tags.  I used re because when I was looking at other threads that is what they were using so I tried to implement it.  Can I ask what does the ?: mean I know the | means or.  Thanks for those suggestions I will definitely check them out.

Comment: @user1943221: The `(?:..)` syntax denotes a *non-capturing* group. If I left out the `?:` part the group would capture, and `findall()` changes behaviour when there are capturing groups; it *only* returns the values in capturing groups. When there are no capturing groups, it returns the whole match instead, which is what we wanted here.

Comment: Sorry for just getting back to you.  Thanks for the explanation!!